# Create React Native Github repository

Tags: react-native, github

I create a new new React native App and push to GitHub repository. It shows my repository as Objective-C project. How I can change this to JavaScript project?
I Added .gitignore file to stop unwanted files to upload to Github.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't care about this, unless you want to use your github to show your skills. This is automatic and displays the most used language in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing was to create a file called .gitattributes in the root folder of repository, and give it these contents:

```
* linguist-vendored
*.js linguist-vendored=false
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a .gitattributes file to your repo. In that file add these lines

```
special-vendored-path/* linguist-vendored
*.js javascript linguist-vendored=false
```